# HTMLUNIT third party analyze of Website, Issues with Javascript being not found

Tags: java, javascript, web-scraping, htmlunit, web-testing

I am creating a program that would automate the process of checking data on a website to make sure everything is running correctly (aka a health check).  I am having issues with the javascript. Here is the source code for the page.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Webpage</title>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="common.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="homepages.js"></SCRIPT>
<script language="JavaScript" src="write_cookie.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<FRAMESET COLS="160,*" FRAMESPACING=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 BORDER=0>
 <FRAMESET ROWS="51%,42%,7%" FRAMESPACING=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 BORDER=0>
<FRAME SRC="left.jsp" MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 NORESIZE="NORESIZE"    SCROLLING="auto" NAME="leftframe">
<FRAME SRC="bottomleft.htm" NAME="bottomleft" NORESIZE="NORESIZE"  SCROLLING="auto">
<FRAME SRC="copyright.jsp" SCROLLING="NO" NAME="copyright" NORESIZE="NORESIZE">
 </FRAMESET>
 <FRAMESET ROWS="30,*" cols="*" FRAMESPACING=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 BORDER=0>
<FRAME SRC="header.jsp" SCROLLING="NO" MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0  NORESIZE="NORESIZE" NAME="topbuttons">
  <FRAME SRC="content.jsp" MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 NAME="main" NORESIZE="NORESIZE">
  </FRAMESET>
 </FRAMESET>
   <noframes></noframes>
  </HTML>
```

If I understand correclty, if I am trying to reference a element that is in "Content.jsp" wouldnt I just have to .

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    // Get the first page
    HtmlPage homepage = webClient.getPage("webpage");
    List<HtmlElement> mainF =homepage.getElementsByIdAndOrName("My Account");
```

However it does not detect the element and I receive this error...

> Apr 8, 2012 4:11:48 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'https://Webpage/common.js', but got ''.
>
> Apr 8, 2012 4:11:48 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'https://Webpage/mui/homepages.js', but got ''.
>
> Apr 8, 2012 4:11:49 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'https://Webpage/mui/write_cookie.js', but got ''.
>
> Apr 8, 2012 4:11:50 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'https://Webpage/mui/menuDisplay.js', but got ''.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the
language="JavaScript"
and replacing them with the more correct type="text/javascript"

Just a note to future-proof your code.  You have a lot of stuff in uppercase.  It might be worthwhile to create all future projects with lowercase tags in HTML.  I've noticed you also have nothing before the opening  tag, that is very unusual.  One day you will pay dearly for this style of coding; a good start would be to investigate what a properly-formed html file looks like, and then create a basic html file and then run it through the de facto validator : http://validator.w3.org/

I think the problem is that the tool is having problems with the html code, because it's not valid HTML.  Run it through the validator.